# Limit Memory Usage of Kafka Streams

Tags: apache-kafka-streams, rocksdb

Is there a way to limit or define the max memory usage of a kafka streams application?  I have enabled caching with my state stores but when I deploy in Openshift I get OOM killed on my pods.  I have checked I have no memory leakes and all my state store iterators are being closed.

I have updated my RocksDbConfigSetter to the recommendations found in https://github.com/facebook/rocksdb/wiki/Setup-Options-and-Basic-Tuning#other-general-options with no luck.

When I look at the state store directory the size is about 2GB.  Currently have 50GB of memory allocated to the application and it still OOMs

Comment: Atm, it's not possible to define a strict limit on memory usage.

Comment: So am I suppose to give my openshift more and more memory until it does not OOM?  I am already at 20GB.  Does startup (rebuilding the statestore) use more memory.  App was running fine and when I went to restart the pod it OOM.

Comment: It looks like there might be more to your problem than what you summarized here.

Comment: Try to estimate your required memory : https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/sizing.html

Comment: I am using the defaults so its 112mb * 20 partitions and I am using a key value store.  So that is 2240 mb.  I am confused, is that in addition to the memory usage of actual data as described by scenario 3.

Comment: I am encountering the same scenario even with RocksDB tuning? Is there any soft limit of memory or setting the heap size "-Xms -Xmx" can help?  In scenario 3 from documentation, if we have state store size 20GB, do we need 20GB memory to hold that data in memory?

Comment: Hey @MatthiasJ.Sax, has the situation changed? Can we set a strict memory usage?

Comment: I guess :) -- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-8215 -- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-8324 -- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-8323 -- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-8637 -- Worth to upgrade to at least 2.3

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax We are also seeing memory issues in our environment and trying to implement RocksDBConfiSetter. 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65814205/kafka-streams-limiting-off-heap-memory

Comment: @Chris Were you able to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Calculate how much state-stores are getting created for your application and the total size of application

Use

```
StreamsConfig.topicPrefix(TopicConfig.RETENTION_BYTES_CONFIG)
```

It will limit the data stored by the statestore as well as the statestore of the streaming application is saved in kafka topics as well